# PHP how to combine many arrays

Tags: php, arrays, string, null

I have a problem with combining few arrays in such way that index of second array must exist but not as a value of merged array.

For example, these 3 arrays:

```
    $a[0] = 'some A string';
    $a[1] = 'some A string';
    $a[2] = 'some A string';
    $a[4] = 'some A string';
    $a[6] = 'some A string';
    $a[8] = 'some A string';
    $a[10] = 'some A string';

    $b[1] = 'some B string';
    $b[3] = 'some B string';
    $b[5] = 'some B string';
    $b[7] = 'some B string';
    $b[9] = 'some B string';
    $b[11] = 'some B string';

    $c[0] = 'some C string';
    $c[1] = 'some C string';
    $c[3] = 'some C string';
    $c[6] = 'some C string';
    $c[9] = 'some C string';
    $c[12] = 'some C string';
    $c[15] = 'some C string';
```

should be rewritten to:

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => some A string
        [1] => some A string
        [2] => some A string
        [3] => blabla
        [4] => some A string
        [5] => blabla
        [6] => some A string
        [7] => blabla
        [8] => some A string
        [9] => blabla
        [10] => some A string
        [11] => blabla
        [12] => blabla
        [15] => blabla
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => blabla
        [1] => some B string
        [2] => blabla
        [3] => some B string
        [4] => blabla
        [5] => some B string
        [6] => blabla
        [7] => some B string
        [8] => blabla
        [9] => some B string
        [10] => blabla
        [11] => some B string
        [12] => blabla
        [15] => blabla
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => some C string
        [1] => some C string
        [2] => blabla
        [3] => some C string
        [4] => blabla
        [5] => blabla
        [6] => some C string
        [7] => blabla
        [8] => blabla
        [9] => some C string
        [10] => blabla
        [11] => blabla
        [12] => some C string
        [15] => some C string
    )
```

There can be more than 3 of such arrays.
How to achieve such result to have exacly same number of keys for each array filled in with 'blabla' instead of values taken from other tables?

Comment: One solution could be to loop the array, if the key is missing, set 'blabla' to that index, then break when you reach index 15.

Comment: If none of your arrays have [16] but one of the  arrays has [17], do you want your data to skip [16] or to set it to blah for all of them?

Comment: key index number is unknown, one table can have 15 other one can have 1500 there is no limit for key, every 'blah' must be put to table in these places where other tables has useful data

Comment: So how do you determine when you should stop inserting 'blahs' into the array, if one can have 15 entries, another can have 1500? What determines the limit of the array?

Comment: key index number is unknown, one array can have 15 other one can have 1500 there is no limit for key, 

taking 'c' array: every 'blah' must be put to 'c' at these places where other arrays 'a' and 'b' has useful data without overwriting values of 'c' and vice versa same wat to other arrays combined all will all

Comment: combining a with b:
foreach($b as $key=>$val) {
        !isset($a[$key]) ? $a[$key] = 'blabla' : null ;
}
ksort($a, SORT_NUMERIC);

Comment: Yes, you said that already, but to which point should it *stop* to insert 'blah' to the empty indexes? When it reaches the last index? At a specific number?

Comment: then oposite way a with b, but how to combine 10 of such arrays ? :)

Comment: @DanielGalecki Does my solution work? Or is it logically incorrect?

Comment: I suspect that the solution needs finding the largest array size and back fill the resulting arrays till that index.

Answer (score 0):

Edited dynamic length of array

```
<?php
    $a = array();
     $a[0] = 'some A string';
        $a[1] = 'some A string';
        $a[2] = 'some A string';
        $a[4] = 'some A string';
        $a[6] = 'some A string';
        $a[8] = 'some A string';
        $a[10] = 'some A string';


    end($a); 
    $last = key($a);


    $returnarray = array();    
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $last; $i++) {
        if(isset($a[$i])) {
            $returnarray[] = $a[$i];
        }else{
           $returnarray[] = "blabla";
        }
    } 

    print_r($returnarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you will need to get a list of keys.

The easiest way to do it is to create mega array and get all of its keys.

```
$mega=array();

$mega=$a+$b+$c;
```

Then you want to get all the keys with array_keys();

```
$keys=array_keys($mega);
```

then you want to iterate through your keys and figure out which arrays have and which don't. If you only have 3 arrays, then you can manually iterate through all 3.

FULL VERSION OF WORKING CODE:

```
<?php
$a[0] = 'some A string';
$a[1] = 'some A string';
$a[2] = 'some A string';
$a[4] = 'some A string';
$a[6] = 'some A string';
$a[8] = 'some A string';
$a[10] = 'some A string';

$b[1] = 'some B string';
$b[3] = 'some B string';
$b[5] = 'some B string';
$b[7] = 'some B string';
$b[9] = 'some B string';
$b[11] = 'some B string';

$c[0] = 'some C string';
$c[1] = 'some C string';
$c[3] = 'some C string';
$c[6] = 'some C string';
$c[9] = 'some C string';
$c[12] = 'some C string';
$c[15] = 'some C string';
$mega=array();
$mega=$a+$b+$c;
$keys=array_keys($mega);
$resulting_array=array();

foreach($keys as $key)
{
        if(isset($a[$key]))
                $resulting_array[0][$key]=$a[$key];
        else
                $resulting_array[0][$key]='blah';

}

foreach($keys as $key)
{
        if(isset($b[$key]))
                $resulting_array[1][$key]=$b[$key];
        else
                $resulting_array[1][$key]='blah';

}

foreach($keys as $key)
{
        if(isset($c[$key]))
                $resulting_array[2][$key]=$c[$key];
        else
                $resulting_array[2][$key]='blah';

}

var_dump($resulting_array);
```

OUTPUT:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(14) {
    [0]=>
    string(13) "some A string"
    [1]=>
    string(13) "some A string"
    [2]=>
    string(13) "some A string"
    [4]=>
    string(13) "some A string"
    [6]=>
    string(13) "some A string"
    [8]=>
    string(13) "some A string"
    [10]=>
    string(13) "some A string"
    [3]=>
    string(4) "blah"
    [5]=>
    string(4) "blah"
    [7]=>
    string(4) "blah"
    [9]=>
    string(4) "blah"
    [11]=>
    string(4) "blah"
    [12]=>
    string(4) "blah"
    [15]=>
    string(4) "blah"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(14) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "blah"
    [1]=>
    string(13) "some B string"
    [2]=>
    string(4) "blah"
    [4]=>
    string(4) "blah"
    [6]=>
    string(4) "blah"
    [8]=>
    string(4) "blah"
    [10]=>
    string(4) "blah"
    [3]=>
    string(13) "some B string"
    [5]=>
    string(13) "some B string"
    [7]=>
    string(13) "some B string"
    [9]=>
    string(13) "some B string"
    [11]=>
    string(13) "some B string"
    [12]=>
    string(4) "blah"
    [15]=>
    string(4) "blah"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(14) {
    [0]=>
    string(13) "some C string"
    [1]=>
    string(13) "some C string"
    [2]=>
    string(4) "blah"
    [4]=>
    string(4) "blah"
    [6]=>
    string(13) "some C string"
    [8]=>
    string(4) "blah"
    [10]=>
    string(4) "blah"
    [3]=>
    string(13) "some C string"
    [5]=>
    string(4) "blah"
    [7]=>
    string(4) "blah"
    [9]=>
    string(13) "some C string"
    [11]=>
    string(4) "blah"
    [12]=>
    string(13) "some C string"
    [15]=>
    string(13) "some C string"
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks! This logical solution is worth trying. I will check it later and come back with answer :)

Comment: @DanielGalecki I just modified it again. Please use the latest version.

Comment: Dimi, thanks, that was that. You understood the problem very well. I used your idea and produced something like this: https://pastebin.com/S7HvRVUX

Answer (score 0):

This the exact what you want.

```
$a[0] = 'some A string';
$a[1] = 'some A string';
$a[2] = 'some A string';
$a[4] = 'some A string';
$a[6] = 'some A string';
$a[8] = 'some A string';
$a[10] = 'some A string';

$arr=[];

for($i=0; $i<=15; $i++){
    if(!isset($a[$i]))
        $a[$i]='blabla';
    array_push($arr, $a[$i]);
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: No, that is not, cause nobody know how big is any array.